# Why is a Map not a "true" collection?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I came across this in the Java Collections tutorial:

"Note also that the hierarchy consists of two distinct trees — *a Map is not a true Collection*."

This confuses me, as I always thought a Map was a collection. Can anyone shine some light on what this means?

What is a "true" collection and why is a Map not one of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is not a *true* `Collection` because it doesn't extend the [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface. Besides that, it is a collection by concept.

Comment: More precisely, it's a true *collection*, but not a true `Collection`.

Comment: +1, I could not express this so briefly and so clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Map is an association between keys and values. Other (true) collections are ... collections of similar values. It is almost impossible to consolidate so different data structures under the same interface. This is the reason why Collections implement interface `Colletion` and maps implement interface `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is not a true `Collection`.Because the `Collection` interface is largely incompatible with the `Map` interface. If `Map` extended `Collection`, what would the `add(Object)` method do?

The two interfaces have very different semantics. If you need the values or the keys of a Map as collections, you can always use `keySet()`/`values()`.

Please refer [Java Collections API Design FAQ:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/designfaq.html#a14)